# Angular PWA Service Worker not calling localhost server on offline mode

Tags: angular, mongodb, server, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a project using Angular and PWA, running on this server:

```
http://localhost:8080/heroes
```

And I have a mongodb api on another server:

```
http://localhost:3000/heroes
```

As you can see, the URL is the same, but different ports and this is working fine when online. But when I switch to offline, I would expect it to keep working since the server api mongo is localhost, but it is giving me this error:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null,
    "headers": {}
  },
  "status": 504,
  "statusText": "Gateway Timeout",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000/heroes",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/heroes: 504 Gateway Timeout",
  "error": null
}
```

Maybe run mongodb in another route will work, I don't know honestly, thanks everybody.

---

I added my project angular pwa to a free server for test "heroes1234.000webhostapp.com", in section home you can test jsons api gets, it works to my localhost:3000/heroes, fine in online, but not working in offline mode. thanks

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: it works fine, I upgrade my project testing, to an url for you can watch it. look: 
angular pwa : http://heroes1234.000webhostapp.com/home

Comment: so when I trying to call and json from api url like this- http://heroes1234.000webhostapp.com/ it works, but when i try to call to my local databse mongo works, but only in ONLINE, i want it works offline, thats why im using offline, http://localhost:3000/heroes

Comment: HTTPS is a PWA requirement

Comment: Localhost is considered "secure", therefore no need to have HTTPs while developing locally. The issue seems more related to the fact that the SW is not aware which HTTP GET calls to cache.

Comment: but, i dont wanna cache gets, what i want to do, is that in offline mode, i can make an http:localhost get, it is posible? thanks

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña As per your requirement you need to implement offline database synchronization with yo ur api when user comes to online. for this you have some option to implement like wise first you have 1. `IndexedDB` 2. `FaunaDB` 3. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync these are options. When user in offline you can store data local and when comes online you can call your backed API and takes offline data to online mode..

Comment: there is another way to save local data? because indexb has a max size of 5mb, and maybe im working with data with a size 300mb sometimes. thanks @GaurangDhorda

Answer (score 2):

How do you define the URLs to be cached in the `ngsw.config.json` file?
If you want to cache data requests (using performance or freshness strategy), you should define the taget URLs within the "dataGroups" array, like in the example below:

```
"dataGroups": [
{
  "name": "jokes-cache",
  "urls": [
    "/icanhazdadjoke.com"
  ],
  "cacheConfig": {
    "strategy": "performance",
    "maxSize": 5,
    "maxAge": "15m"
  }
}
```

I wrote an [article on how to create a PWA with angular](https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular), caching static assets and network calls, in case you want to deepen the topic.

Comment: but i dont wanna cache url, i want that in mode offline, i can make a request to localhost server, it is posible?

Comment: How can your SW provide some data while offline if not in the cache? This is not how PWAs work. You need to have static assets or data requests cached locally (client side shipping the requests). Then once offline, the SW intercepts the app requests and delivers the data if this is available locally in the cache.